# Why did the start-search find WinDiff, but the "see more results" did not?

Tags: windows-7, search

I clicked on the start button, and typed "WinDiff" (without the quotes). I got a result pointing me to it (it's a program). I then clicked on "See more results" and got nothing. Why?

(Its location is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\x64\WinDiff.Exe".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I think I got it. The Start-Search searches for Programs and the Control-Panel, the regular search probably does not.